# Unable to query over many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

does anybody know how to query DB in EF Core for many-to-many relationship, but more like left outer join from one side?

Let me explain what I mean.

Currency.cs

```
public class Currency
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string   ISOCode { get; set; }

    public string   Symbol  { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<RegionCurrency> RegionCurrencies { get; set; }
}
```

RegionCurrency.cs

```
public class RegionCurrency
{
    public Guid CurrencyUID { get; set; }

    public Guid RegionUID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrencyUID")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RegionUID")]
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

Region.cs

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid     UID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string CountryISOCode         { get; set; }

    public List<RegionCurrency> RegionCurrencies { get; set; }
}
```

MyContext.cs

```
public class LookupTablesContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Currency> Currecies { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<RegionCurrency> RegionCurrency { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RegionCurrency>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.CurrencyUID, t.RegionUID })
            .HasName("PK_RegionCurrency");

        modelBuilder.Entity<RegionCurrency>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Region)
            .WithMany(p => p.RegionCurrencies)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RegionUID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RegionCurrency>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Currency)
            .WithMany(p => p.RegionCurrencies)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CurrencyUID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>()
            .HasIndex(c => c.ISOCode)
            .HasName("UX_Currency_ISOCode")
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .HasIndex(c => c.CountryISOCode)
            .HasName("UX_Region_CountryISOCode")
            .IsUnique();
    }
}
```

My query:

```
var result = ctx.Currencies
                  .Include(c => c.RegionCurrencies)
                  .ThenInclude(rc => rc.Select(rcs => rcs.Regions)) // This seems to be wrong
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ISOCode == "EUR");
```

I also tried to use includes as you can see below on the picture:

[image: many-to-many relationship include]

Please note, that RegionCurrencies table can contain 0-N relations and I want to get Currency entity even there's no record in RegionCurrency table.

This (and similar tries) ended up in exception like this:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The property expression 'rc => {from RegionCurrency rc in rcs select [pts].Regions}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

```
Dependencies:
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
```

I cannot find any working example. But certainly I'm just blind.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as shown below.

```
var tag = ctx.Tags.Include(t => t.PostTags)
             .ThenInclude(p => p.Post).FirstOrDefault(d => d.TagId == "2");

var posts = tag.PostTags.Select(c => c.Post).ToList();
```

**Note :** Sometimes VS doesn't show intellisense properly. So beware of intellisense :D . One solution may be for that is: close VS and start a new instance of it.

***For example :*** intellisense is working fine for this `.Include(t => t.PostTags)`.But beware on this `.ThenInclude(p => p.Post)`.You have to write it without relying on intellisense. Hope Microsoft will fix this issue on the future releases of VS.

**Result :**

value of `tag` :

[image]

values of `posts` :

[image]

**Test data :**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update :**

It's working.Please see the code.

```
var currency = db.Currecies.Include(t => t.RegionCurrencies)
                           .ThenInclude(p => p.Region)   
                           .FirstOrDefault(t => t.UID == Guid.Parse("0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e"));

var regions = currency.RegionCurrencies.Select(c => c.Region).ToList();
```

**Result :**

value of `currency` :

[image]

values of `regions` :

[image]

**Git Repo :** [**EfCoreManyToMany**](https://github.com/Sampath-Lokuge/EfCoreManyToMany)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this won't work. 
I assume, that Include(t => t.PostTags) will return IIncludableQueriable<Tag, List<PostTag>>, so there will be no p.Post property for ThenInclude, but only List methods because List<PostTag> type will be on output from first Include.

Comment: Than you for updating your answer. Please see my updated question (image). It's a screenshot from a real project where the relationship is defined the same way as on the sample project.

Comment: I have given the solution for the EF core doc's example.Now you're showing different code set.So then you must show all your models code and etc ...

Comment: OK, I didn't want to make so too long question when definition is equal to public sample.... but when you think it's necessary... I'll do it.

Comment: Updated to real project code. Hope that this will help.

Comment: please see the **Update** section.

Comment: The problem is, that there's no p => p.Region predicate in ThenInclude. Please see picture in my question. There's a list of RegionCurrency entities obviously. Something must be wrong - mayme in my code or definition. Have you tested my code against your query?

Comment: yes,I have tested your code and it's working fine.please see the attached **git repo** on my post above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll give you feedback ASAP. I'm too busy right now. I'll also have to pull older version from a repo because my project/db structure has changed a lot. I have suspicion on some missing "using" in a controller, but I have to verify it.

Comment: OK sure.Take your time :)

Comment: Hey, I got it! The problem is, that I was relying on intellisense. It does not provide "Region" property for "ThenInclude" method. When I wrote the whole lambda expression, then it started to be recognizable by Visual Studio and project can be compiled, but still can't be found by VS intellisense. Could you please change your answer a little bit? Maybe add some "beware of intellisense" warning on top so I can mark your answer as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please highligh in your note that devil was hidden in .ThenInclude(p => p.Post)? E.g. intellisense for Include(t => t.PostTags) works good. Restart of VS did not help me... I really had to "hardcode" it against intellisense.

Comment: Done that.please see it :)